# How do I split an edge with a key shortcut?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow, edges

How do I split an edge by using a shortcut? I've done it many times, but I've forgotten how I did it.

In picture below, I've done it manually, but I'd like to know how to do it with shortcut.

[image: split]

Comment: Select an edge and pres V.

Comment: Or in this particular example, select the top vertex.

Comment: you find this and many other related options (with shortcuts) using CTRL-V

Answer (score 1):

Select the vertex, face, or edge that you want to rip, and press V.  You then can move the separated vertice(s) around, or right-click (or possibly left-click, if you select with the right mouse button) so that they are on top of each other but not connected.